# Update new foreign key column of existing table with ids from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulk

I have an existing table to which I have added a new column which is supposed to hold the Id of a record in another (new) table.

Simplified structure is sort of like this:

**Customer table**

```
[CustomerId] [GroupId] [LicenceId]  <-- new column
```

**Licence table <-- new table**

```
[LicenceId] [GroupId]
```

The Licence table has a certain number of licences per group than can be assigned to customers in that same group. There are multiple groups, and each group has a variable number of customers and licences.
So say there are 100 licences available for group 1 and there are 50 customers in group 1, so each can get a license. There are never more customers than there are licences.

Sample

```
Customer
[CustomerId] [GroupId] [LicenceId]
 1            1         NULL
 2            1         NULL
 3            1         NULL
 4            1         NULL
 5            2         NULL
 6            2         NULL
 7            2         NULL
 8            3         NULL
 9            3         NULL

Licence
[LicenceId] [GroupId]
 1            1
 2            1
 3            1
 4            1
 5            1
 6            1
 7            2
 8            2
 9            2
 10           2
 11           2
 12           3
 13           3
 14           3
 15           3
 16           3
 17           3

Desired outcome

Customer
[CustomerId] [GroupId] [LicenceId]
 1            1         1
 2            1         2
 3            1         3
 4            1         4
 5            2         7
 6            2         8
 7            2         9
 8            3         12
 9            3         13
```

So now I have to do this one time update to give every customer a licence and I have no idea how to go about it.

I'm not allowed to use a cursor. I can't seem to do a MERGE UPDATE, because joining the Customer to the Licence table by GroupId will result in multiple hits.

How do I assign each customer the next available LicenceId within their group in one query?
Is this even possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
with c as (
      select c.*, row_number() over (partition by groupid order by newid()) as seqnum
      from customers c
     ), 
     l as (
      select l.*, row_number() over (partition by groupid order by newid()) as seqnum
      from licenses c
     )
update c
    set c.licenceid = l.licenseid
    from c join
         l
         on c.seqnum = l.seqnum and c.groupid = l.groupid;
```

This assigns the licenses *randomly*.  That is really just for fun.  The most efficient method is to use:

```
row_number() over (partition by groupid order by (select null)) as seqnum
```

SQL Server often avoids an additional sort operation in this case.

But you might want to order them by something else -- for instance by the ordering of the customer ids, or by some date column, or something else.

Comment: Awesome, it needed a little bit of tweaking, but that was exactly what I needed! Thank you!
I upvoted, but because of my non-existent reputation it doesn't show.

Comment: Also to clarify my edits
1) I edited it such that step one was ORDER BY GroupId, as I needed each group to start with a new sequence.
2) I edited the JOIN ON to be c.seqnum = l.seqnum AND c.GroupId = l.GroupID;  Otherwise it would keep on assigning Ids from the first group over and over.

Comment: @JH91 . . . Only the change to the `on` clause is needed.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon has put it very well in his answer.
Let me break it down into simpler steps for you.

Step 1. Use the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign a SeqNum to the Customers. Use PARTITION BY GroupId so that the number starts from 1 in every group. I would ORDER BY CustomerId

Step 2. Use the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign a SeqNum to the Licences. Use PARTITION BY GroupId so that the number starts from 1 in every group. ORDER BY LicenseId because your ask is to "assign each customer the next available LicenceId within their group".

Now use these 2 queries to update LicenseId in Customer table.

Comment: Thank you for your addition. Gordon's answer together with yours helped me to do exactly what I wanted. Except in step one I needed to order by GroupId instead of your suggested CustomerId, because I needed each group to start with the new sequence.
I did upvote, though it doesn't show!